# Enlarging of images on mousehovering

Tags: html

I want to enlarge image when cursor is placed on it in my help file .
what should I do to implement this in my html page?
Is it related with CSS code or JQuery

What should I do for that?

Comment: welcome at SO! Please take a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You really should try something yourself first, post some code, etc. This questions as it is now is way too broad and extensive to answer (or do you just want a plugin?)

Comment: Maybe you should just try googling for: "css3 image zoom" or "jquery image zoom"

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using CSS3 transforms if your clients are using modern browsers.
You can do something like this:

```
.img-zoom{
...
}

.img-zoom:hover{
transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

You can also add a transition for a better experience:

```
.img-zoom{
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
...
}
```

Of course you will have to add support to other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Zoomer from DynamicDrive website. Works a treat.